# Input string was not in a correct format. Want integer as input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I develop a web application using asp.net in visual studio. There is a login form using data from SQL. At first, user login process was went well with below code.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Usertbl where Username='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(ds, "reg");
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
    {
        isLoggedIn = true;
        Session["New"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
    } 
    else 
    {
        isLoggedIn = false;
        Label3.Text = "Incorrect username or password";
    }
}
```

Then I add another role of user for login which I called as admin (because I want different role of user redirected to different webpage after logged in) and their data was from another SQL table so I add another sql command :

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Admintbl where username='" + TextBox1.Text + "' 
and password = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'
";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(ds, "reg");

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
    {
        isLoggedIn = true;
        Session["New"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");

    } 
    else 
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Usertbl where Username='" +
        TextBox1.Text + "' and 
    Password = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'
    ";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(ds, "reg"); //**Source Error happens here**

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
        {
            isLoggedIn = true;
            Session["New"] = TextBox1.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
        } 
        else 
        {
            isLoggedIn = false;
            Label3.Text = "Incorrect username or password";
        }
    }
}
```

After I tried login using `Admintbl` it can logged in but not for my `Usertbl`, it said

> *Input string was not in a correct format.*

In stack trace it said

> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store `<nani>` in Username Column.  Expected type is `Int32`.

So I tried login using **username : 1234** and **password : 0** , then it shows success.

It want integer as my username. I don't understand why, could somebody explain to me?

Comment: Did you define your column as an integer column? Also, please don't create SQL statements like this. You're creating a [SQL Injection vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I define username as nvarchar(50) . It only want integer when I add another SQL command

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check the query `CommandText` and make sure it has the user id and password. If not then that is your issue.

Comment: Well, you need to use parameterized query here - use parameters with `SqlDbType` to ensure correct data type, e.g. `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;`. Also `Username` column data type should be declared as `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: Did you got your problem solved? if still not, reply...we will help

Comment: I deleted Usertbl and created new table with same value and design. So this time, using the new table, I successfully logged in using 'nani' as username. I still don't know what is the real problem though..